# How to use multiple set condition in better way in soql query

Tags: query

Is it possible to make query dynamic.I have sets like this:

```
 if(SetOfParentId.size()>0 || Set1.size()>0 || SetOfGSSDuplicateCase.size()>0 || SetOfLegacyDuplicateOfCase.size()>0 ||Set11.size()>0)
```

Using OR Condition querying the record

```
   if(SetOfParentId.size()>0 || Set1.size()>0 || SetOfGSSDuplicateCase.size()>0 || SetOfLegacyDuplicateOfCase.size()>0 ||Set11.size()>0){
        for(Case et : [select id,Vmstar_Id__c,GSS_Duplicate_Case__c,Duplicate_Of_Case__c,GSS_Build_Number__c,GSS_Product_Version__c from Case 
                       where Vmstar_Id__c IN : SetOfParentId 
                       OR  Vmstar_Id__c IN :SetOfGSSDuplicateCase 
                       OR Vmstar_Id__c IN :SetOfLegacyDuplicateOfCase
                       OR GSS_Build_Number__c in :Set1
                       OR GSS_Product_Version__c in :Set11]){
                           if(et.id!=null){
                               MapOfParentId.put(et.Vmstar_Id__c,et.id);
                           }if(et.GSS_Duplicate_Case__c!=null){
                               MapOfGSSDuplicateCase.put(et.VMstar_Id__c,et.GSS_Duplicate_Case__c);              
                           }if(et.Duplicate_Of_Case__c!=null){
                               MapOfDuplicateOfCase.put(et.VMstar_Id__c,et.Duplicate_Of_Case__c);
                           }if(et.GSS_Build_Number__c!=null){
                               Set3.add(et.GSS_Build_Number__c);
                           }if(et.GSS_Product_Version__c!=null){
                               Set33.add(et.GSS_Build_Number__c);
                           }
                       }
```

If Even one set values goes null also it will fetch all the records ***(Its based on OR condition)***.It shouldnt happen like that I need to build the query based on set value present or How to make check this condition better way?

i Need to use the query in better way,I dont want to retrieve large number of records.

If any set values goes,I will get large set of records

Comment: Why not simply remove null from each Set?

Comment: i didnt get it.can u please explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the null values beforehand, and everything should work:

```
SetOfParentId.remove(null);
Set1.remove(null);
SetOfGSSDuplicateCase.remove(null);
SetOfLegacyDuplicateOfCase.remove(null);
Set11.remove(null);
if(SetOfParentId.size()>0 || Set1.size()>0 || SetOfGSSDuplicateCase.size()>0 || SetOfLegacyDuplicateOfCase.size()>0 ||Set11.size()>0) {
```

This works because the filter is effectively ignored when the set is empty. Just make sure that there are no null values in your sets.

Comment: thanks sfdcfox.i like this solution.. i dont know why cant I thought like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with Dyanmic `SOQL` in that case, you can check the size of individual sets and can keep on adding the `Where` clause where set's size is greater than 0. If size if not greater than 0, you can ignore that `Where` clause.

Something like below should work

```
string soqlString = 'select id,Vmstar_Id__c,GSS_Duplicate_Case__c,Duplicate_Of_Case__c,GSS_Build_Number__c,GSS_Product_Version__c from Case';
if(SetOfParentId.size()>0 || Set1.size()>0 || SetOfGSSDuplicateCase.size()>0 || SetOfLegacyDuplicateOfCase.size()>0 ||Set11.size()>0){
    soqlString += ' Where ' 
}
boolean whereClauseAdded = false;
if(SetOfParentId.size()>0){
    whereClauseAdded = true;
    soqlString += ' Vmstar_Id__c IN :SetOfParentId';
}
if(SetOfGSSDuplicateCase.size()>0){
    if(whereClauseAdded)
        soqlString += ' OR Vmstar_Id__c IN :SetOfGSSDuplicateCase';
    else 
        soqlString += ' Vmstar_Id__c IN :SetOfGSSDuplicateCase';

    whereClauseAdded = true;
}

if(SetOfLegacyDuplicateOfCase.size()>0){
    if(whereClauseAdded)
        soqlString += ' OR Vmstar_Id__c IN :SetOfLegacyDuplicateOfCase';
    else 
        soqlString += ' Vmstar_Id__c IN :SetOfLegacyDuplicateOfCase';

    whereClauseAdded = true;
}

//query the records using Database.query method
List<Case> requiredCases = Database.query(soqlString);

for(Case et : requiredCases){
    //all other existing logic
    if(et.Duplicate_Of_Case__c!=null){
        MapOfDuplicateOfCase.put(et.VMstar_Id__c,et.Duplicate_Of_Case__c);
    }
    //all other existing logic
}
```

Similarly, you can add other where clauses as well. Note, above code is just a pseudo code, there can be a better way of doing it as well.

And then you can use `soqlString` to query for records using `Database.Query` method and can continue with your existing logic

**Note : All the sets that you will be using in dynamic SOQL needs to be in local scope, other wise it won't work.**

Comment: hi vijay.I need to add the value to map as well. MapOfGSSDuplicateCase.put(et.VMstar_Id__c,et.GSS_Duplicate_Case__c);..how to do that in this situation

Comment: That is something which you are doing post getting the records. You can still continue to do the same. Only change is the way you query your records. Instead of using static query, now you will have to use Dynamic SOQL

Comment: Can you help me to build complete logic..please update your ans..i got confuse

Comment: @SFDCFAN Updated the answer

Comment: recieved error: System.QueryException: unexpected token: List<Case> requiredCases = Database.query(soqlString);

Comment: As mentioned all sets should be in local scope. Debug the soqlQuery and check if is properly built.

Comment: set in local scope.

Comment: thanks vijay.i will do upvote for your time and patience